# searching for a string in a file using python faliure

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x

I am using this code to search for emails in a particular file and write them into a another file. I have used 'in' operator to make sure that the email are not duplicated.
But this code does not get executed after the  `for line in f:` line.
Can any one point out the mistake i have made here?

```
tempPath = input("Please Enter the Path of the File\n")
temp_file = open(tempPath, "r")
fileContent = temp_file.read()
temp_file.close()

pattern_normal = re.compile("[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+")

pattern_normal_list = pattern_normal.findall(str(fileContent))

with open('emails_file.txt', 'a+') as f:            
    for item in pattern_normal_list:            
        for line in f:
            if line in item:
                print("duplicate")
            else:
                print("%s" %item)
                f.write("%s" %item)
                f.write('\n')
```

Comment: The trouble is the first time you run this ``emails_file.txt`` will be empty so there will be no line to read so you'll never get around to adding one. @Torxed is showing you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New solution:

```
tempPath = input("Please Enter the Path of the File\n")
temp_file = open(tempPath, "r")
fileContent = temp_file.read()
temp_file.close()

pattern_normal = re.compile("[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+")

addresses = list(set(pattern_normal.findall(str(fileContent))))
with open('new_emails.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(addresses))
```

---

I think your logic *was* wrong, this works:

```
addresses = ['test@wham.com', 'heffa@wham.com']

with open('emails_file.txt', 'a+') as f:
    fdata = f.read()
    for mail in addresses:
        if not mail in fdata:
            f.write(mail + '\n')
```

Without reading to much into your code,
it looks like youre looping line by line, checking if the address you've also looping through exists in the line, if it doesn't you append your e-mail to it? But in 99% of a 100 lines the address will not be in the line, hence you'll get an unwanted addition.

Output of my code snippet:

```
[Torxed@faparch ~]$ cat emails_file.txt 
test@wham.com
Torxed@whoever.com
[Torxed@faparch ~]$ python test.py 
[Torxed@faparch ~]$ cat emails_file.txt 
test@wham.com
Torxed@whoever.com
heffa@wham.com
[Torxed@faparch ~]$
```

Comment: I got your point my logic was wrong. But i changed as you said still it writes duplicate records.
The source file i get emails contain duplicate records.and this code writes all of them into emails.txt file.
The changed code snippet: 
with open('emails_file.txt', 'a+') as f:
                fdata = f.read()
                for item in pattern_normal_list:
                    if item not in fdata:
                        print("%s" %item)
                        f.write("%s" %item)
                        f.write('\n')

Comment: Added a updated version, where you **1** reads the file containing douplicate email-addresses. Then, filter that.. wait a minute.. erm..

Answer (score -2):

```
for line in f:
```

Shouldn't you first call f.readlines()?

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
```

Check this.

Comment: You don't have to with the `with open() as f` statement, it's essentially exploads down to, f being a file handle and if you iterate through that file handle you'll get one line at a time as per default implementation in Python.

Comment: @Torxed: but only once; OP is trying to go through the entire file for each item in a list, which won't work without a `seek()` (although I agree this answer could be clearer).

Comment: @Torxed: You don't need the `with` statement for this. Opening a file with `f = open(filename)` and reading with `for line in f` works. Of course using `with` is always a good idea.

Comment: Fair enough, it's not a requirement but should be in the usage described :) But again, you're right, +1